# Coinbase lost my transaction from Bitstamp

Tags: transactions, wallet, coinbase.com, bitstamp

I'm moving my coins out of Bitstamp I was looking for another exchange. I have sent 0.00007 BTC to just test the transaction. I got the address where I want to send coins to from coinbase.com/myAccountName. Apperently this address changes after a while.

I got a mail from Bitstamp to verify my transaction, what I accepted.

> You requested to withdraw 0.00007000 bitcoins to address
>   1Kr8jaHPqEfwd1ZXMh6PHg2fhM5vqCYAQH.

A few minutes after my transaction it was finished on Bitstamp. I copied [the address to the blockchain](https://blockchain.info/address/1Kr8jaHPqEfwd1ZXMh6PHg2fhM5vqCYAQH) and I saw it was confirmed and verified my the network.

Then I went back to coinbase.com/myAccountName and I saw the address was changed...
I never got a mail or a conformation the funds have been transferred on my coinbase account.

I thought Coinbase was doing a lot of effort to make this dummy proof?
What did I do wrong? Isn't coinbase.com/myAccountName made to do an easy transfer?

I'm using Bitfinex now, worked great. Very happy with the exchange!

Comment: https://coinbase.com/addresses has a list of addresses you can receive. Does the address appear there?

Comment: It only has one address what is different than the address I use to transfer the money... I gave the link of this topic to the support of coinbase, lets way for the result. It would be a shame if a new person to Bitcoin lost a lot of money by this bug. It loses trust in Bitcoin...